# MS Office 2003/wine/

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

Ubuntu 12.04.2, wine installed as administrator (not root), MS Office 2003 installed as administrator (not root).

Word, Excel, etc. work fine under administrator account but can't get either to run under a user account.

From user account found path to WINWORD.EXE (/home/administrator/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/OFFICE11)

From terminal, execute: wine WINWORD.EXE

Error: IOPL not enabled

winecfg: configured library - gdiplus (native, builtin) then (native, windows)
Same error.

Should I reinstall MS Office under user account?

What am I missing?

Comment: You do know that "Administrator" has no special meaning in Linux, right, that "Administrator" is just a regular user account? The somewhat-equivalent of Administrator in Windows is the root account in Linux.

Comment: When creating an account I have the option of setting it up as a Standard or Administrator account. If there is no difference then why ask?

Comment: I guess what it meant by Administrator is that the user can use `sudo` and gain root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand, you can run Word as user Administrator, but when trying to run it from another different account (user300246 for instance) you get errors.

In fact seems absolutely normal, let me explain. You installed it as "Administrator" user, so the files has the correct (read/write) permissions for that user. When you try to run it from other user (user300246, for instance), perhaps Winword.exe is trying to read/write from/to a file which is owned by Administrator, which throws the error.

Try to install Winword with a different user and run from the same user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was afraid that it might have something to do with permissions. I thought that I might have to install it for each user. Fortunately, there is are only 2 users for each PC I have to convert. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why use MSOffice 2003?

The current Libreoffice has a everything and more functionality, is free, runs native in linux, is easy to install, works very well with DOC files.

if you still insist you need it, check the AppDB entry for MSOffice2003 in www.winehq.org for troubleshooting.

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2735

Comment: I agree that Libreoffice is better in many respects. However, my use requires MS Office. I am using 2003 because I have an unlimited license. I am replacing a bunch of XP machines and don't have the money to purchase new hardware and security reigns at this point. Hence, the move to Ubuntu.

Comment: Good move. Any machine that runs XP will run linux for a very long time. I guess you run a training lab and your curriculum asks for Microsoft Office? you will probably have enough space on the drives for a dual installation (MSOffice&Libroffice).